# In Haskell, how to construct lists and make substitution between it

Tags: list, haskell

In Haskell, I am going to construct 2 list of chars; one is the 26 chars in the alphabet by the original`(A,B,C,D,....Z)`, all in uppercase. And the other one is the same list but the order of letters is changed, like`(B,H,A,I......S)`. And now I am also going to make a substitution between these two lists, such as when the input is `B` then returns `H`, `C` returns `A`.

Can anyone could help me out of this?

Comment: what's the actial question? can you include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2):

List literals in Haskell use square brackets `[]`, first of all.

Second of all, I don't know the wording of your assignment, but free of constraint, I would use an association list instead of two lists.  An association list is a list of pairs of the form `[(a,b)]`. The key operation on an association list `lookup`, defined in `Data.List`. Look at the type signature and see if you figure out what it does.

If you start with two lists, you can zip them up.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe 

codec = zip "ABCDEF..." "BHAI..." -- String ~ [Char]
encode = map $ flip lookup codec

plainText = "The secret fox"
encodedText = encode plainText
```

Notice that this gives you a list of `[Maybe Char]`. I leave it to you to figure out how to extract the chars, since it's actually a design choice. (Do you want to just omit characters that don't show up in the codex, or  insert a '!' or something so that the user knows data has been lost? Lots of options here. Notice how the Maybe monad is forcing you to explicitly handle this case).

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the modified alphabet is:

```
"ORXBMDTCIGJYKAVLSWFNUQEHZP"
```

The code should look like:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

alphabet = ['A'..'Z']
mapping = zip alphabet "ORXBMDTCIGJYKAVLSWFNUQEHZP"

according letter = (snd . fromJust . (find (\t -> f t letter))) mapping
    where
        f (x, y) letter = x == letter

main = print $ according 'H'
```

`mapping` would create the correspondence between alphabet and a modified version. And `according` would return letter from a modified, based on the original one.

Comment: You can simplify that to `according = fromJust . flip lookup mapping`